# TextView appearing in preview but not on emulator and real device

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to run my app in real device and facing this problem:

[It looks like this in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a0OP.png)

[It looks like this in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbhFa.png)

Textview with id **textViewSignUpForAccount** is displaying in preview but not on emulator and real device.

what should be the problem?

I tried hours fixing this issue but no success.

here I am placing my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NotificationActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/notification_frag_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:text="All activity"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/iron" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relativeLayout" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProfileIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/inboxicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSignUpForAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Messages and notifications will appear here"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup_in_notificationsActivity"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Sign up"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would guess that the runtime theme is not the same as that used in the preview, and your text is ending up with a color that blends in with the background. What happens if you add `android:textColor="@color/black"` to that `<TextView>`, like you have it on the others?

Comment: Yeah...This solved my problem. million Thanks.